# How to show a pop-up for first time users

Tags: reactjs

As a first time user of cookies, I am trying to create a modal that only displays for first-time users to my website.

I am using react and have downloaded the universal-cookie package. So far I am able to check if the cookie exists and if so hides the modal.  The second part of the function if the cookie does not exist then should create a cookie and display the modal.  At present, the cookie is created but no modal is displayed.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styles from './index.module.css';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';



function Slide1() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true); //Displays Modal
  const cookies = new Cookies('registered');

  const handleCookie = () => {
    if (cookies.get('registered')) {
      return setIsOpen(false); //Modal does not open if cookie exists
    } else if (!cookies.get('registered')) {
      cookies.set('registered', 'true', {
        path: '/',
      });
      return setIsOpen(true); //Creates a cookie and shows modal.
    }
  };
```

Comment: Can you show your full component ?

Comment: @P.E.Joëssel. Please see edited

Comment: have you tried using useEffect?

Comment: Look at @fahimchowdhury's answer, you need to use useEffect

Answer (score 4):

Try this, Replace

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
```

import useEffect,

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
```

Instead of using handlCookie(), use

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if (cookies.get('registered')) {
    setIsOpen(false); //Modal does not open if cookie exists
  } else if (!cookies.get('registered')) {
     cookies.set('registered', 'true', {
      path: '/',
     });
     setIsOpen(true); //Creates a cookie and shows modal.
  }
},[])
```

Remove this from div

```
onLoad={handleCookie}
```

Comment: Good to know. It would be great if you mark my answer as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1/ You can remove the `return` from these lines I think :

`return setIsOpen(false);` & `return setIsOpen(true);`

2/ And in your JSX, you can put `{isOpen && (` instead of  `{isOpen ? (`

3/ Then you can remove the `: null` in the JSX